# Make radio button's ripple effect work with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on material design radio button and trying to make its ripple effect working but I'm having trouble with the right JavaScript functions.

Based on MDL, the effect activates on mousedown (not really sure) and while still holding it, and on mouseup it fades out. I already have the ripple container and I think I will be needing an animation for fading it out but for now, I will stick on to basics which don't have animations.

**CSS**

```
.radio-ripple {
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: -9px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.radio-ripple.is-active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

My full code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLnL3cuj/). Using jQuery, it will be much easier.

I am still a beginner in JS/jQuery library, so I came here to ask for some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.radio').mousedown(function(e) {
    $(this).find('span').addClass('is-active').fadeIn('fast');
  }).mouseup(function(e) {
    $(this).find('span').addClass('is-active').fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

```css
.radio {
  position: relative;  
}

.radio-ripple {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: -9px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.radio-ripple.is-active {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radioActive" />Has ripple
    <span class="radio-ripple 1"></span>
  </label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radioActive" />Has also a ripple
    <span class="radio-ripple 2"></span>
  </label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label class="radioButton">
    <input type="radio" name="radioActive" />Ordinary
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: no, I'm making it my own version of material design radio button. I'm not using the MDL framework.

Comment: I have changed the example, i hope this will help :)